# Why regex fail when I used lowercase?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Could you please tell me why my regex test fails when I use a lowercased `a`?

Here is my code:

```
  var a = "A0201418"

  if (/^A\d{7}$/.test(a)) {
      console.log('=====true');
  } else {
      console.log('false');
  }
```

**Expected output**
"A0201418" . true
"a0201418" . true .

I want a pattern where start with "A" follow with `7` digit number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the case-insensitive flag (`i`):

```
if (/^A\d{7}$/i.test(a)) {...}
```

If you're using the `RegExp` constructor, pass `"i"` as the second argument:

```
RegExp("^A\\d{7}$", "i")
```

Comment: Joseph, please don't try to edit my code - comment it, and if I see it'll improve the quality of the post, I'll change it.